# Codeigniter Pagination Links Error After ID

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

sorry if my question is duplicate, i have a problem with my codeigniter pagination. My url is: http://mysite/news/category/26/(page number), i have only 5 data and the page limit is 10, but the generated links active on page 3, i believe that is because of id/26/

This is my model :

```
function categpry($id){
    $string_query = "SELECT * FROM news n JOIN category c ON n.category_id = c.id_category AND n.category_id = $id ORDER BY n.category_id DESC";
    $query = $this->db->query($string_query);
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('news/category/' . $id);
    $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = '10';
    $num = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $offset = ( ! is_numeric($offset) || $offset < 1) ? 0 : $offset;
    if(empty($offset)){
        $offset = 0;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $news = $this->db->query($string_query." limit $offset,$num");
    return $nes;
}
```

the generated links is 1 - 2 - **3**, its should be no link because i only have 5 data
 
please help me on this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I fixed it with change the script with this :

```
function category($id){
     $string_query = "SELECT * FROM news n JOIN category c ON n.category_id = c.id_category AND n.category_id = $id ORDER BY n.category_id DESC";
    $query                      = $this->db->query($string_query);
    $config['base_url']         = site_url('news/category/' . $id);
    $config['total_rows']       = $query->num_rows();
    $limit                      = $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"]      = 4;
    $config["use_page_numbers"] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    if($this->uri->segment(4))
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)-1)*$limit;
    else
        $page = 1;
    $news= $this->db->query($string_query." limit $page,$limit");
    return $news;
}
```

Thank you